# How to recover a deleted test run in Polarion

Tags: recover, disaster-recovery, polarion

I accidentally deleted a test run which holds important data.

It holds the work of multiple teams. I was deletin another test run but mistakingly I deleted another with
The one I wanted. It would be much help if I can recover it from any directory.

I would like to get it recover

Answer (score 0):

You need to recover the files via direct access in SVN.
For this you need to have some knowledge about the file structure.

An Instruction for WorkItems can be found here(it uses TortoiseSVN for doing the relevant SVN operations):
https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/polarion/recovering-deleted-polarion-data-part-1-of-2/

The folder you need to examine is: `<Polarion Projectfolder>/.polarion/testing/testruns`

You can find the "Polarion Projectfolder" in the Adminpage of the project.